# How to disable HDRI in Magick.Net version 7

Tags: magick.net

As you may know in the version 7 of ImageMagick, HDRi is enabled by default. How can I disable this functionality when I am using Magick.Net in C#. 
Please do not answer the command line solution I need to do it in C#.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick 7 has HDRI enabled by default but with Magick.NET this will only happen when you use the Q16-HDRI version of Magick.NET. When you use the Q8 or the Q16 version you will not have HDRI enabled.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might be enabled even for Q8 or Q16.